# Duplicate people in SharePoint Online Search result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, web-part, people-search, duplicate

In SharePoint Online Search result, I have some people duplicated and I don't know why.

One have information like number et the other one nothing only the same name.

[image: Results of search directory i created]

I've already checked the user profiles and people are unique there.
Can somebody help me ?

Comment: can you double check whether the UPN (user principle name) is properly updated with the email id and it is same as login name. this will resolve the most problems with the login, search results and so on. once this is properly updated perform a directory sync again to replicate the changes to office 365 identities.

Comment: Hi, i tried to check it but, i dont see anything incorrect, or maybe i need some screenshots if you can help men thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact scenario and it was driving me crazy.  I found that there is a Query Rule called "People Name in People Search" which was adding the duplicate result when you search on a user's exact name.  I made the query rule inactive by going to:

Site Settings > Query Rules > Change Result Source to "Local People Results" > Select the "People Name in People Search" rule and made it inactive.

[image]

As far as I can tell no negative affects, and my duplicate results are gone. Hope this helps!